# Facebook Insights API - App News Feed counts for Impressions and Clicks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I have been exploring the [Facebook insights FQL table](https://web.archive.org/web/20151015045538/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights), and I assumed I could get to all of the data which is available via the insights dashboard from the FB app admin.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to get the data shown on the "Insights > News Feed" set of reports. Particularly, I am trying to get to the stats of the feed stories generated by my app.

Is it possible to get to this data right now? I can't seem to find it.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the data I am trying to get to with the API]

Comment: did you find this? I have been looking for the same thing. Thanks

Comment: I haven't... moved on for now in hopes the put out something better soon :/

Comment: That's about where I am too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use insights connection for [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

The User, Page, Application and Group objects have feed connections containing post objects that represent their walls. In addition the User and Page objects have a connection named posts containing Posts made by the User and the Page respectively.

A post from Facebook Platform: https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_10150189643478553

Comment: documentation says that insights data is available is the post was made by a page.  I would be interested to know if it is available for posts made by an app (not made by a page).  Do you know if it does?

Comment: I'll try to test it today, and tell you the results.

Comment: I tested this. The Post connection would show you insights for all posts, even if they were made by an app.

Comment: How exactly do you access that object? Is it doable with FQL? I also wanted to be more specific about how my posts are made: They are initially created via the JS SDK FB.ui method.

Comment: I access that object with post/insights method of the Graph API. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: Thank you for the reposne! I've extended my answer.